# Making sure chromedriver and google-chrome are the same version in Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running a Python script on Ubuntu that uses Selenium and Chromedriver.

Here's the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
```

After reading about this error, I realize it may be due to incompatibility between chromedriver and the version of of chrome I'm using.

1. `chromedriver -v` gives me:

   ```
    ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.130
   ```

   `google-chrome-stable -version` gives me:

   ```
    Google Chrome 78.0.3904.70
   ```

   `chromium-browser -version` gives me:

   ```
    Chromium 79.0.3945.130
   ```

However, when I set the binary location to be chromium-browser, I still get the same error.

Both chromedriver, chromium-browser, and google-chrome-stable are in `/usr/bin`.  2 questions:

1. Should the above code theoretically work if Chromedriver and Chrome are the same version?  Why would chromium-browser throw an error if it's same version as Chromedriver?
2. In command-line, How can I update google-chrome / google-chrome-stable to match the specific Chromedriver version?  Looking for best-practice here on how to easily keep these both synched to the same version of each other.  I could probably run `sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable` but how do I know this will give me the correct Chrome version to match Chromedriver?